# vb.net dataview grid won't add record and doesn't update after data is modified independently

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, dataview

I have a dataview grid bound to a datasource at run time. The datasource is filled from an access database via a DataAdapter. The data fills and displays correctly, and updates to existing rows seem to work OK but I have two problems:

1. When I type something in a new row and then press return or switch to a different row, I want the DataAdapter to add that row then and there to the database so I can retrieve the Autonumber index of the new record from Access and use that to add an associated record in a different table (Entries, a many to many linking table). This isn't happening. In the RowLeave event I have         adapter.Update(dsSentences) and then I check for the new row, but the RowCount doesn't reflect its presence even though the newly added data is visible in the grid, and the adapter.Update doesn't seem to have triggered the Insert query that I specified in the DataAdapter. So nothing is added.
   (edit: OK, so the new row has not yet been added when this event is fired. Which event should I then use to commit the data and retrieve the Autonumber primary key for my new record? I've tried UserAddedRow but that one fires before you've entered any data into the new row.)
2. THe second problem is that I need to update the data independently and then have the grid reflect those changes. How do I do that? Is there some call that will force the grid to get the updated data from the DataAdapter via the Dataset? Any help would be much appreciated. I'm almost ready to dtop the whole idea of binding data and do it all through code, Data binfing is supposed to save time but I'm finding it labyrinthine and unpredictable.

FWIW here's the query I'm using to fill the grid:
PARAMETERS nIdCollection Long;
SELECT tblSentences.IdSentence, tblSentences.SentenceText, tblSentences.SentenceParsed, Not IsNull([tblSentences]![SentenceParsed]) AS HasParsed, Entries.IdEntry
FROM tblSentences INNER JOIN Entries ON tblSentences.IdSentence = Entries.IdSentence
WHERE (((Entries.IdCollection)=[nIdCollection]))
ORDER BY Entries.SortValue;

As you can see, it requires a record in Entries. After I've entered a new record in tblSentences, before there are any entries the IdEntry will be null assuming it shows up at all. That's why I need to intercept directly after the Insert, add the record to Entries and requery to keep everything in order. You could do it all in an SQL stored procedure but I have to use Access.

Edit: After a lot of googling I've come to the conclusion that what I'm trying to do = add a record to a table through an additional INSERT query apart from the one handled by the DataAdapter, every time a new row is added - simply can't be done if you are using data binding. I am going to have to delete all my code and start from scratch populating the grid through code (unbound). I think it's the only way to do what I want. I will leave this here as a warning to anyone else not to make my mistake of trying to use Data binding when your data is coming from more than one table. Bad mistake.

Comment: *add that row then and there to the database so I can retrieve the Autonumber .. and use that to add an associated record in a different table* - you don't need to - you have the datatable column be autoincrement/seed/step of -1 and let them head into negatives, you have a data relation (fk type) between the tables in the dataset, you add child rows that refernece the negative parent id values, you save the parent with a tableadapter configured to "refresh the datatable" and the generated ID is retrieved into the parent table on the set, then the datarelation replicates that to the child rows

Comment: *I need to update the data independently and then have the grid reflect those changes* - it should work that way out of the box, but I suspect you aren't currently leveraging the mechanisms that make it easy..

Comment: "ou have the datatable column be autoincrement/seed/step of -1 and let them head into negatives" I don't think you can do that in Access - just checked and the options for Autonumber are Increment or Random. Other than that your solution seeems ingenious.

Comment: I guess what I need to know here is the order things happen. I'm trying currently to get the Autonumber in the UserUpdatedRows event, but it turns out that even there, and evne calling Adapter.Update, nothing has been added to the DB. So is there an event after the Adapter has done the Insert that I can use?

Comment: I'll try and explain this more clearly.. Currently in my UserUpdatedRows (and previously in ROwChanged) I had two things: first, a call to adapter.Update(dsSentences)  and then a loop where I go through dsSentences to find one that has a null value in the FK so I can call a query that corrects this by adding a record to TblEntries. What I'm finding is that the dsSentences doesn't yet contain any new row. Like I didn;t just add one. So I need to know in what event or at what moment I can loop through the rows in dsSentences, find the one with the null value and ...

Comment: *I don't think you can do that in Access* - it's not in access, it's in a dataset which is a vb.net side data container for data downloaded out of an access db.. I don't know when I'll get time to post an answer on it, alas, because it needs more explanation than comments

Comment: OK don't worry and thanks for your time. I've decided to do it a different way without binding. THe problem was that if you set the datatable to have a primary key and adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey, the FK instead of the expected null value contains garbage. Without this, you can't add a record without getting an error "PK can't be null". No way round this, so data binding is basically out.